# syntax Function.Build().Run();

Tags: c#, syntax

I am coming from a c background and starting to learn a bit more about c#.
Going through some code i often see these statement

> CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
>
> Object.FunctionA().FunctionB();

I looked everywhere and cannot find where this type of syntax is described.
I am assuming it means:

> Object.FunctionB(); 
>   Object.FunctionA();

But I am just guessing at this point, if you can help me clarify that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, this means `Object.FunctionA()` returns some instance of a type (let´s call it `MyType`), on which you call `FunctionB`. The latter isn´t defined on `Object`, instead it is defined on `MyType`.

Comment: This is often referred to as a "fluent interface", you can write something that resembles a sort of sentence, and the options you have at every step are limited and thus known to you. Instead of figuring out if you have to call FunctionA before or after FunctionB, you might only be able to call FunctionB on the object returned from FunctionA.

Comment: In many cases, the same type is returned, in many cases a different type is returned.